# Azure Logic app, AzureAD remove group members, insuficcient permission

Tags: permissions, azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps

I'm creating a Azure Logic app to replace members of defined Azure AD group. I have used this blog  (https://geekshangout.com/logic-app-remove-azure-ad-group-members/) as of base for my job, but so far remove-member fails with insufficient permissions.

Basically logic app does:

- Retrieve list of users from Azure SQL table with specific query: OK
- Get list of users from AzureAD group : OK
- For-each member:

  - remove member.objectID from azure group object ID:: Fails with following error:

    ```
    "body": {
        "error": {
            "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
            "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
            "innerError": {
                "date": "2022-02-10T07:32:44",
                "request-id": "--------------",
                "client-request-id": "------------"
            }
        }
    }
    ```

So far: I re-created the logic app and taking care of:

- Admin consent is given as described in the blog, by using the Global Admin account.
- I can see in the 'Enterprise Applications' blade this 'logic app' created
- permissions should be correct: API name: Microsoft graph, Claims: Directory.readwrite.all, group.readwrite.all, user.readwrite.all, offline_access , as of Microsoft documentation describes (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuread/)
- Awaited now about 24 hours, so no 'cloud-lag' should be problem.

Should this 'Enterprise Application' have an additional permissions? If so, what and where?

- Already tried to create a custom role with permissions described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/custom-group-permissions

"Life is not a problem to be solved, but a reality to be experienced"
~T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the user with which you set up the Logic Apps connection for Azure AD is authorized to manage this group's membership (e.g. which would be the case if this was a Global Administrator), the most likely cause for this is that the group you are trying to change membership for is a role-assignable group.

Role-assignable groups are special groups to which directory roles can be assigned. Adding a member to the group is equivalent to assigning a directory role to that member, so neither of the delegated permissions Directory.ReadWrite.All nor Group.ReadWrite.All allow this. (For regular groups, either of them would be sufficient.) The app would also need to be granted the delegated permission RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory.

From the look of things, the built-in Logic Apps connector for Azure AD is not built to handle group membership for role-assignable groups.

If you really do need to be able to do this, you could [update the delegated permissions granted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.identity.signins/update-mgoauth2permissiongrant?view=graph-powershell-1.0) to the connector to include RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory, but you should be very careful about this (and your entire solution, including the SQL database and the Logic App), as misuse could carry significant security risks.

Comment: I re-created target group without 'role assigment group' and it worked. Thank you.